# Let $A$ be a square matrix with all its diagonal and anti-diagonal elements equal to zero; is $A$ not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Example for $3\times 3$: $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&3&0\\1&0&7\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

I tried out some examples and it seems right, but I honestly have no idea how to prove that it is not invertible in general; any help is really appreciated.

Comment: seems right for matrices smaller than $4\times4$

Comment: The first and the last column of your $A$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Antoine Yeah I know I just gave an example of how these matrices look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0}$?

Comment: phew, I missed out on bigger matrices, thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: This matrix is its own inverse!